# Calling Webmethod containing byte array (as in paramaeter)parameter with ksoap2 on android

Tags: ksoap

There is WEB  service written on C# with next method:

```
[WebMethod]
public string ByteArrTest(byte[] Buffer)
{
if (Buffer == null) return "buffer is null";
else return Buffer.Length.ToString() + " is buffer length";
}
```

i 'ld like call this method from android device using Ksoap2 library alike belove (simplified):

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;

new MarshalBase64().register(envelope);
        envelope.encodingStyle = SoapEnvelope.ENC;

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(this.getNameSpace(), this.getMethodName());

PropertyInfo pi4 = new PropertyInfo();
        pi4.setName("Buffer");
        byte [] b="this text".getBytes();
        pi4.setValue(b);
    pi4.setType(byte[].class);
// request.addProperty("buffer", "bytes".getBytes);
request.addProperty(pi4);
 envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = 
new    HttpTransportSE(this.getURL());//

androidHttpTransport.call(this.getSoapAction(), envelope);
Object response = envelope.getResponse();
//next implementation
```

Responce always is  "buffer is null"
what is incorrect or wrong?
Thanks for any attention

Answer (score 0):

Posting the whole of your method in Android calling the web service would help more.

I'm using KSoap in an Android project I'm currently working on and I'm retrieving strings. Heres one of my methods modified to match what you need:

```
    private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/";
private static final String URL = "Your url link to your web services asmx file";

        public static String ByteArrTestCall(byte[] t) {

    String resTxt = null;
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "ByteArrTest");
    // Add the property to request object
    request.addProperty("Buffer", t);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
    try
    {
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION+"ByteArrTest", envelope);
    SoapPrimitive receivedString = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
    resTxt = receivedString.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        resTxt = androidHttpTransport.requestDump;
        return e.toString() + resTxt;
    }

    return resTxt;
}
```